# Asp Net Core MVC: How to get Column of aspnetusers in a partialview

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I added a user-defined column `hasAvatar` to the aspnetusers table.
but how can i get the information of the current user, when i am in the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` ?

I want to get the information like

```
@if (myUser(User).hasAvatar==true)
{
    <p>..avatar</p>
}
else
{
    <p>please login</p>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a view component:

```
public class LoginViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public LoginViewComponent(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

Then, move the contents of `_LoginPartial.cshtml` to `Views\Shared\Components\Login\Default.cshtml`. Add an `@model` declaration of `ApplicationUser`, and then you can use `Model.hasAvatar`, or any other property on `ApplicationUser`.

Finally, where you were previously rendering the `_LoginPartial`, replace that code with:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Login");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a `UserManager` in your view and get the current user from it:

```
@inject UserManager<User> UserManager
@{
    var myUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
}
```

You can also check if the current request is authenticated with:

```
@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```